# Footer Positioning Problem

Tags: html, css, footer

[Here](http://glamourunderground.com/fitness/) (on Chrome 10) the footer seems to be aligning with the side bar (too far to the right) instead of center like it's supposed to be.

I didn't edit the footer's CSS. I was editing the sidebar and the index when this happened, but it's so far down the page that I didn't notice 'til later, so I have no idea what the problem is.

Any suggestions welcome! Thank you :)

Tara

UPDATE: I've checked all the DIVs are correctly closing. Some were missing in the side bar, and that's [fixed the problem on the front page](http://glamourunderground.com) but [not on sub pages or articles](http://glamourunderground.com/fitness/). Now there is a black line appearing at the top (under the menu) that appears to be the #footer!!. I can't understand why it's there.

[image]

Comment: its not a css problem, your footer container is inside your right column. I recommend to set it at the bottom of your #wrapper and validate your html, there are some missing divs

Comment: Thanks @Rito I tried this and it fixed the home page but not the other pages for some reason :( Still working on it...

Comment: The footer is working now! @Rito was right I was missing a div. Unfortunately, the side borders of the content are now missing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wrapper `#casing` contains floated elements, which are not cleared for following elements.

```
#casing { overflow: hidden; }
```

This should fix it for modern browsers. I recommend [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) for better understanding and other clearing solutions.

Comment: Thank you @rito you've been a big help

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear your floated elements by adding `clear: left;` to your `#footer` css.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, I'll try this though it seems to be fixed now so I won't be able to tell if it makes a difference - but the footer does tend to move for no apparent reason from time to time so hopefully this should help =)